# OpenLdap inetOrgPerson object class attribute missing : "middlename"

Tags: redhat, ldap, openldap, solaris, apache-ds

I have an openLDAP installed on my server. Please refer image below for the details.

[My OpenLDAP version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w939y.png)

My issue is that i can't find middlename attribute under inetOrgPerson object class, which is needed for my use case. I tried to search for oid and syntax so that i'll try to add a new attribute to inetOrgPerson, but i can't find too and not sure if it's possible. I saw here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-middlename and the attribute id is : 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.34 and tried to compare it to here : https://ldap.com/ldap-oid-reference-guide/ but the oid is ref Attribute Type. My question is how can i get the middlename attribute in openLDAP?

Comment: Please do not reference textual data, like "My OpenLDAP version" as external image. Text is searchable, images are not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your own object class mentioning *middleName* as optional attribute in `MAY` clause (or `MUST` to make it mandatory).

You have two options:

- Define a custom `STRUCTURAL` object class with `SUP inetOrgPerson`
- Define a custom `AUXILIARY` object class which you can add to existing *inetOrgPerson* entries.

Note that OpenLDAP strictly follows rules in [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512) disallowing changing a structural object class of existing entries.

See also: [OpenLDAP FAQ -- Answers related to slapd(8) schema configuration](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/219.html)